# How to preserve the full-width spaces at the end of text lines when using itext 7?

Tags: java, itext7

In order to align the text in each line by column, sometimes it is necessary to add full-width spaces at the end of the line, but when I use itext7 to output pdf, the spaces at the end of the line will be cleared. How can I keep this space (the space must be full-width)? Please give me some advice, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried non- breaking spaces there?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.